# Display a date in a format and store it in other (Datepicker in Laravel)

Tags: laravel, date, datepicker

I'm working in laravel and I want to show in my Bootstrap Datepicker field a date in a format (dd/mm/yyyy) but I want to store it in format (yyyy/mm/dd).

are there some property in Datepicker to do that? this is my input:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="fecha_nac"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control CalendarioDP" 
             name="fecha_nac" placeholder="Colocar fecha"
             value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%d/%m/%Y') }}">
</div>
```

My Script:

```
<script>
    $('.CalendarioDP').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "es",
    });
</script>
```

When I let the format in script like this way, the date is showed it and stored it in a format (dd/mm/yyyy),

[Showed it in the input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmJIW.png)

[Stored it in the DB, is the first date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPFHG.png)

but I want it in (yyyy/mm/dd).

I have used "Torzer DateTime Mutator" and "protected $dates" but I want to know if there are exist a simple DaterPicker property to declaret just once in the script and not to specify each field that I want to Convert like in Torzer.

Comment: Have you considered changing the date format for the database to use the default date property, then use an accessor to get the format when retrieving it?

Answer (score 1):

put this in your `controller`

```
public function Store(Request $request)
{
 //here put you format date to store in your DB
 $object->date = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->fecha_nac)->format('Y/m/d');
}
```

Comment: @EduardoQuiñonez this is the right way how to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script>
$('.CalendarioDP').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    language: "es",
});
</script>
```

Or update your input type into this.

`<input type="text" id="CalendarioDP" data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd'>`

Comment: I understand that, but I want to show the date in a format dd/mm/yyy, but store it in a format yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: @EduardoQuiñonez I see.